# Let ABC be the triangle with the following properties

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I am stuck with the following problem:

[image]

Can someone point me in the right direction (about problem no. 59)?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: What have you attempted ?

Comment: Prove that triangles $ABC$ and $BDC$ are similar. That gives you an equation between $BC, CD$ and $AC$. Then find a relation between $EB$ and $EC$. If you do that, you are done.

Comment: Thanks..i have got it now..I will add my answer soon.

Comment: Yes, that's it. You've got it right!

Comment: Thank you so much @ Futurologist

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Consider the $\triangle ABC $ and $\triangle BDC $. We see from the figure that 
$\angle BCD =\angle ACB=z+x$. Now, considering the figure ,
$$z+x+x+ \angle BDC=180^{\circ}=x+x+z+x+y \implies \angle BDC=x+y.$$ Hence 
$\triangle ABC $ and $\triangle BDC $ are similar. 
So, $\frac{BC}{AC}=\frac{DC}{BC}\implies \frac{BC}{9}=\frac{4}{BC} \implies BC=6.$

The perimeter of $\triangle BEC$ being $13$, $BE+EC+6=13 \implies BE=EC=\frac{13-6}{2}=3.5$